# Connecting ethers.js to a light client

Tags: go-ethereum, light-clients, ethers.js

I'm trying to connect ethers.js to a `geth` light client. A connection seems to form, but with no indication that I'm able to receive the right data.

Here's the `geth` command I'm using:

```
geth --rpc --rpcport 8555 --rpccorsdomain "*" --syncmode "light"
```

And here's the `ethers.js` code I'm using (in an Observable notebook).

```js
ethers = require("ethers")
provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:8555")
provider.getBlockNumber() // this block number comes out at 0 which doesn't sound right at all
```